# me guarda el pdf pero nulo - php

Tags: php

buen dia, desde un input file cargo un archivo pdf y lo envió a mi .php para que el nombre del archivo quede guardado  en base de datos y el pdf quede almacenado en un carpeta que se llama pdf hasta ahí todo funciona correcto pero en el momento que el archivo queda guardado .pdf queda  en la carpeta pdf queda nulo y no abre.

```js
//index.php

<?php

$txtFoto2=(isset($_FILES['txtFoto2']["name"]))?$_FILES['txtFoto2']["name"]:"";

$redondear = rand(5, 80);    

include ("conexion/conexion.php");

   
    $Fecha = new DateTime();
     $sentencia=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pruebas(archivo) VALUES (:txtFoto2)");
     

    $nombreArchivo=($txtFoto2!="")?$Fecha->getTimestamp()."_".$redondear.".pdf":"default.pdf";

 //aqui esta el problema el archivo guarda en la carpeta pdf pero queda nulo, el pdf no abre
 file_put_contents('pdf/'.$nombreArchivo, $txtFoto2);
      
      
      $sentencia->bindParam(':txtFoto2',$nombreArchivo);
      $sentencia->execute();
      
    header("Location: https://miweb.com/#/Pruebas");
    exit();
      
   

?>
```

```html
<html>

<form method="post" action="https://miweb.com/index.php" target="_parent" name="reset" encType='multipart/form-data'>

 <input id="txtFoto2" name="txtFoto2" type="file"
                 accept="application/pdf" />
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit"> Guardar</button>
  </form>              
                
</html>
```

Comment: Me parece que tiene que llamar file_get_contents() antes de file_put_contents() o usar move_uploaded_file() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php (en ingleés.)

Comment: al cambiar file_put_contents por  move_uploaded_file() no me guarda nada en la carpeta pdf, el problema esta en "file_put_contents('pdf/'.$nombreArchivo, $txtFoto2);" algo estoy llamando mal

Comment: Aparte de que no haces validaciones, usas el nombre del archivo subido como contenido para el PDF, no es que quede `nulo`, sino que no tiene el formato adecuado. Definitivamente, es mejor usar `move_uploaded_file()` como ya te sugirieron.

Comment: utilizando move_uploaded_file() encontre la solución , pero igual me toco cambiar la validación

Answer (score 0):

```js
//se cambio 
file_put_contents('pdf/'.$nombreArchivo, $txtFoto2);

//por:
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["txtFoto2"]["tmp_name"],"pdf/".$nombreArchivo);
```

Comment: eso quiere decir que `$txtFoto2` no es igual a `$_FILES["txtFoto2"]["tmp_name"]` si hiciste una depuracion paso a paso deviste verlo cuando imprimias por pantalla el valor de `$txtFoto2`.